# JS doesn't load when change mode from development to production in Magento 2.1.9

Tags: javascript, requirejs, magento-2.1.9, production-mode

Website working properly in developer mode when I am changing mode from development to production. JS doesn't load after change mode of production.

Below Error:

```
  GET https://example.com/pub/static/version1530246957/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/mage/requirejs/mixins.js 404 (Not Found)
(index):22 GET https://example.com/pub/static/version1530246957/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js 404 (Not Found)
(index):18 GET https://example.com/pub/static/version1530246957/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/requirejs/require.js 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'https://example.com/pub/static/version1530246957/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/requirejs/require.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
(index):23 GET https://example.com/pub/static/version1530246957/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/fancybox/js/jquery.fancybox.js 404 (Not Found)
(index):21 GET https://example.com/pub/static/version1530246957/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/jquery.js 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'https://example.com/pub/static/version1530246957/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/css/print.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
(index):19 GET https://example.com/pub/static/version1530246957/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/mage/requirejs/mixins.js 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'https://example.com/pub/static/version1530246957/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/mage/requirejs/mixins.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
requirejs-config.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function
    at requirejs-config.js:11
    at requirejs-config.js:12
    at requirejs-config.js:843
(anonymous) @ requirejs-config.js:11
(anonymous) @ requirejs-config.js:12
(anonymous) @ requirejs-config.js:843
(index):21 GET https://example.com/pub/static/version1530246957/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/jquery.js 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'https://example.com/pub/static/version1530246957/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/jquery.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
(index):22 GET https://example.com/pub/static/version1530246957/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'https://example.com/pub/static/version1530246957/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
(index):23 GET https://example.com/pub/static/version1530246957/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/fancybox/js/jquery.fancybox.js 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'https://example.com/pub/static/version1530246957/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/fancybox/js/jquery.fancybox.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
(index):33 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):33
(anonymous) @ (index):33
(index):97 Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function
    at (index):97
(anonymous) @ (index):97
(index):555 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):555
(anonymous) @ (index):555
3(index):554 GET https://example.com/pub/static/version1530246957/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/Ves_All/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0 404 (Not Found)
(index):799 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):799
(anonymous) @ (index):799
(index):894 Uncaught ReferenceError: requirejs is not defined
    at (index):894
(anonymous) @ (index):894
(index):1603 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):1603
(anonymous) @ (index):1603
3(index):798 GET https://example.com/pub/static/version1530246957/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/icon-fonts/font/porto-icons.woff 404 (Not Found)
(index):1665 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):1665
(anonymous) @ (index):1665
(index):1705 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at (index):1705
(anonymous) @ (index):1705
(index):1771 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):1771
(anonymous) @ (index):1771
(index):893 GET https://example.com/pub/static/version1530246957/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/images/select-bg.svg 404 (Not Found)
(index):1664 GET https://example.com/pub/static/version1530246957/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/icon-fonts/font/porto-icons.ttf 404 (Not Found)
(index):1926 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):1926
(anonymous) @ (index):1926
(index):2011 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):2011
(anonymous) @ (index):2011
(index):2033 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at (index):2033
(anonymous) @ (index):2033
2(index):1664 GET https://example.com/pub/static/version1530246957/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/fonts/opensans/regular/opensans-400.ttf 404 (Not Found)
```

I have deploy website multiple times, but the issue is same. 
Can anyone help to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands:

> 1. php bin/magento cache:clear
> 2. sudo chmod 777 var* -R
> 3. sudo chmod 777 pub* -R

Comment: I have given permission 777. but still issue was the same

Comment: have you tried by deploying content ?